# Adapt the font size to the containing div

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a dynamic website, and I'm developping on a 1920*1080 resolution. I have created a div that looks like that : [image: my div]

I tried dealing with the font size by controlling it with the vw attribute, but when I resize my window it looks like that : [image: my div2]

The font is resizing but it does not looks the same way as it does on fullscreen.
How can I handle it ?

HTML :

```
<div id="pb">
            <h1>Ideas</h1>
            <p>
                <img src="graphics/settings-4.png" alt="Image from Flaticons.com" height="20"/> Imagine new business models for in-orbit services around the Earth, right to the moon, or up to Mars.
                <br /><br />
                <img src="graphics/settings-4.png" alt="Image from Flaticons.com" height="20"/> Small is beautiful! Imagine new business concepts of nanosatellites for space systems or drones.
                <br /><br />
                <img src="graphics/settings-4.png" alt="Image from Flaticons.com" height="20"/> Why do we have to use rockets to get to space? Can't we just float a baloon up there? Balloons are cheaper than rockets or airplanes. Imagine how we can move into space!
                <br /><br />
                <img src="graphics/settings-4.png" alt="Image from Flaticons.com" height="20"/> Space tourism can be the future : you could fly to your room tomorrow! Imagine new hostels into space.<br /><br />
                <img src="graphics/settings-4.png" alt="Image from Flaticons.com" height="20"/> Imagine how Earth Observation data can improve land-use management and make smarter cities.<br /><br />
                <img src="graphics/settings-4.png" alt="Image from Flaticons.com" height="20"/> Make Earth a better place to live! Find a way to increase renewable energies’ power thanks to Earth Observation data.
            </p>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#pb {
display: block;
width:80%;
margin-left:10%;
height:70%;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
margin-top:12.5vh; 

#pb h1 {
font-size:1.7vw;
text-align:center;
padding-top:2.8vw; }


#pb p {
font-size:1.2vw;
text-align:center;
padding:2.5vw; }
```

Thanks

Comment: Your images are not styled in your CSS. If you control their `width` with `vw` units, your text should flow the same as you resize your browser.

Comment: the images are not really the things I'm concerned about (even though I should take care of it, didn't see it before), but more the fact that if I resize my window in a certain way (only the height), the text will be out of my div. Is there any way to tell CSS to make the text cover the div (as we can do with background images) ?

Comment: Yes, if you remove the `height: 70%` from your `#pb` element, the text will determine its height automatically. Alternatively you can change that to `min-height` to be at least 70% high, but allow it to grow with its content.

Comment: Anyway, back to font size; most systems can only set the font size to a whole number of pixels; sizes in other units are rounded. So it's not a smooth transition; if you have, for instance, 2vw for a font size, the font size will remain 38px when you decrease the window width from 1920 to 1875 pixels, and will then snap to 37px at 1874 width. Does that match your experience?

Comment: MrLister : the transition seems pretty smooth to me
JonUleis : I'll try with the min-height attribute. 
Any idea on how to deal with it ? vw doesn't seem to be the right solution as if i resize my window vertically only, the size doesn't change (but the size of the div does!)